# Unable to get property 'aoPreSearchCols' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.9. I want to disable the default search functionality of `contains` and add my `equals`. I am trying to add below code:

```
var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable();
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[iCol].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[iCol].bRegex = false;
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[iCol].bSmart = false;
```

Here is the link that I am following where I got the above shared code: https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4096/filtering-an-exact-match/p1

However I am getting an error on this line:

```
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[iCol].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
```

The error:

> Unable to get property 'aoPreSearchCols' of undefined or null reference

How to resolve this error?

Update

```
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/ConvertDatadttoString",
                data: '{"appName":"' + appName + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function OnSuccess(response) {
                    dataObject = eval(response.d);

                   var oTable = $('#JDatadt').dataTable({
                        "order": [],
                        "dom": "Bfrtip",
                        "buttons": ["csv", "excel", "pdf"],
                        "columnDefs": [{ "className": "dt-center", "orderable": false, "width": 20 }],
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "paging": true,
                        "processing": true,
                        "columns": dataObject[0].columns,
                        "data": dataObject[0].Griddata
                    });
              var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
              oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
              oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bRegex = false;
              oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bSmart= false;

                },
                failure: function Onfailure(response) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: `fnSettings()` is returning null/undefined.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `fnSettings()` is returning `null`

Comment: What you have seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bvye2ruq/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my post to show the full code. Now `null` error is resolved. Now I am getting `'iCol` is undefined. My Columns and Rows are generating dynamically. What could be the issue ?

Comment: Where have you defined `iCol`? I noted it's not in your example code as I had to manually add it in the fiddle.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, its not there in my updated post as columns are generated dynamically from `"columns": dataObject[0].columns,
` line of code

Comment: That line doesn't define `iCol` though. It needs to be a numerical value as you're accessing an array by index. For example, you need something like `var iCol = 0;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I defined `var iCol = 0;`  but now `search` functionality is not working at all. Do I need to add something else too? How to make it generic as I am getting my columnname and numbers dynamically and it gets changed from report to report

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any suggestions how to male this work in my case of dynamic column generation or I am following the wrong path ?